# I have two php files one file is inside the subfolder i want to go outside php file

Tags: php, header, subdirectory

I am having two php files one file is inside the subfolder i want to go outside php file.
for this purpose i'm using header `header("Location:order.php");` but this says url not found.

Comment: Try "Location: ../order.php" (if its at the folder level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this 
to go one folder up we use `../` prior to the filename

```
header("Location:../order.php");
```

Comment: if it is two folder means.

Comment: than use two eg.  ../../filename.php

Comment: but this also says url not found.

Comment: header("Location:../../order.php"); make a new file in the sub folder n just test this code within php tags

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you are always placed at the currently working directory....

ie . the Place your PHP file is present...

TO run/include a file present in another place you have to provide its path along with it's name.

There are two options

1. You can provide the absolute FilePath Eg. /home/user/phpfiles/file.php
2. If you want to access something in the Parent or the Subfolders...You can make use of the (.) and (..) operators that point to the current and the parent directory respectively...

Your Problem Can be Solved by using

```
header("Location: ../order.php");
```